# Compare Date Without Time Lambda

Tags: c#, linq

This code breaks I think because there is time in SubmittedDt and DateTimeToday. How do I fix this to filter just by the dates NOT the time.

```
  DailyOrder todaysOrderNotReset = dailyOrders.Where(x => x.SubmittedDt == DateTime.Today && x.IsResetDone == false).First();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x.SubmittedDt
```

should be

```
x.SubmittedDt.Date
```

... though you don't really need the `Where` because First (or FirstOrDefault) should handle what you want.

```
dailyOrders.First(x => x.SubmittedDt.Date == DateTime.Today && x.IsResetDone == false);
```

Comment: ... as well as `DateTime.Today.Date`.

Comment: `DateTime.Today.Date` is unnecessary because `Today` already has no time.

Comment: This got me most of the way there but I needed to use '.Where(a => a.cleaningDate.Value > DateTime.Today)'

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DailyOrder todaysOrderNotReset = dailyOrders.Where(x => x.SubmittedDt.Date == DateTime.Today && x.IsResetDone == false).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DailyOrder todaysOrderNotReset = dailyOrders.First(x => 
    x.SubmittedDt.Date == today && x.IsResetDone == false);
```

When comparing the present date/time against a collection of items, you should preferably first read the current date/time into a local variable, and then use that consistent value for your comparisons. Otherwise, you run a small risk that the present date/time would change during your execution and give unexpected results.